# clang complete add path to includes

Tags: vim, clang-complete

I have simple question today. I'm using this vim config - https://github.com/gergap/vim

The problem is with clang completion. It works but when I want to add more includes to get better completion then nothing is happening - it won't detect new headers.

Get `#include <sys/types.h>` for example. This is what I've added to .clang_complete file placed in directory where my main.c is placed:

`-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/`

which I found by invoking

`find /usr/include/ -name types.h`

What can be wrong? Could you show me some working .clang_complete files with includes to unix headers? Maybe I'll find problem in that way.

This is the output from gcc with -v flag:

```
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

Comment: Path inside `<>` or `""` is *appended* to every include directory you pass to compiler. So if you wan't `<sys/types.h>`, compiler will check if `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sys/types.h` exists. Try using `-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

Comment: @xaizek To be clear. Do I need to compile my programs with clang to make it work? Or compile just once after I added new path?

Comment: you don't need to compile anything to make it work, but I'd suggest restarting Vim after adding new lines to `.clang_complete`, just to be sure it's reloaded (at least this time). I mentioned compiler as completion processes arguments the same way compiler would do, so just put `-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to your `.clang_complete`, restart Vim and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To investigate, run your gcc (or clang) with the `-v` option. This will display the search path used while compiling. On my system (FreeBSD) a simple compile without `-I` options prints

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/clang/3.4.1
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

That should give you an idea what directories to add to `.clang_complete`. **Important**: order matters!

Comment: I've edited my question with output from gcc -v, but I still don't know how this is related to my problem with adding `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/` path to clang complete :)